# Handling the dot in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have a string property called `summary` that has `analyzer` set to `trigrams` and `search_analyzer` set to `words`.

```
"filter": {
    "words_splitter": {
        "type": "word_delimiter",
        "preserve_original": "true"
    },
    "english_words_filter": {
        "type": "stop",
        "stop_words": "_english_"
    },
    "trigrams_filter": {
        "type": "ngram",
        "min_gram": "2",
        "max_gram": "20"
    }
},
"analyzer": {
    "words": {
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "words_splitter",
            "english_words_filter"
        ],
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "whitespace"
    },
    "trigrams": {
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "words_splitter",
            "trigrams_filter",
            "english_words_filter"
        ],
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "whitespace"
    }
}
```

I need that query strings given in input like `React and HTML` (or `React, html`) are being matched to documents that contain in the `summary` the words `React`, `reactjs`, `react.js`, `html`, `html5`. As more matching keywords they have, an higher score they have (I would expect lower scores on documents that have just a word matching not even at 100%, ideally).

The thing is, I guess at the moment `react.js` is split in both `react` and `js` since I get all the documents that contain `js` as well. On the other hand, `Reactjs` returns nothing. I also think to need `words_splitter` in order to ignore the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Basically I'm going to define the `word_delimiter` filter with `catenate_all` active

```
"words_splitter": {
  "catenate_all": "true",
  "type": "word_delimiter",
  "preserve_original": "true"
}
```

giving it to the `words` analyzer with a `keyword` tokenizer

```
"words": {
  "filter": [
      "words_splitter"
  ],
  "type": "custom",
  "tokenizer": "keyword"
}
```

Calling `http://localhost:9200/sample_index/_analyze?analyzer=words&pretty=true&text=react.js` I get the following tokens:

```
{
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "react.js",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 8,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "react",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 5,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "reactjs",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 8,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "js",
        "start_offset": 6,
        "end_offset": 8,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem with names like **react.js** with a keyword marker filter and by defining the analyzer so that it uses the keyword filter. This will prevent **react.js** from being split into **react** and **js** tokens.

Here is an example configuration for the **filter**:

```
     "filter": {
        "keywords": {
           "type": "keyword_marker",
           "keywords": [
              "react.js",
           ]
        }
     }
```

And the **analyzer**:

```
     "analyzer": {
        "main_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": "standard",
           "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "keywords",
              "synonym_filter",
              "german_stop",
              "german_stemmer"
           ]
        }
     }
```

You can see whether your analyzer behaves as required using the analyze command:

```
GET /<index_name>/_analyze?analyzer=main_analyzer&text="react.js is a nice library"
```

This should return the following tokens where **react.js** is not tokenized:

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "react.js",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 9,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "is",
         "start_offset": 10,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "a",
         "start_offset": 13,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "nice",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 19,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "library",
         "start_offset": 20,
         "end_offset": 27,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

For the words that are similar but not exactly the same as: **React.js** and **Reactjs** you could use a synonym filter. Do you have a fixed set of keywords that you want to match?

Comment: Both the documents and the search queries are not predefined. There's nothing I can hardcode. I'm working on a search engine.

Comment: the thing I was thinking about is basically creating a filter that creates for words like "react.js" a synonym that does not contain the dot. In this way both the variants are accepted. Unfortunately I could not find any way in the documentation for doing this.